# MySQL merge two tables with the same IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

In **table_A** I have data from this week, the IDs started from 1 up to 5000.

In **table_B** I have data from last month, whereas the first let's say 3000 IDs conflict with the ones in **table_A**, and it's not the same data for all of the IDs *(ID 1 in table_A is not the same as ID 1 in table_B for example)*.

I want to basically merge **table_B** into **table_A** but getting an ID conflict since some of the IDs I am trying to import already exists.

**Table A**

```
id     timestamp     price
...    ...           ...
518    2021-09-16    20
```

**Table B**

```
id     timestamp     price
518    2021-08-15    10
```

Is there any clever solution out there for this type of issue?

Comment: Please add more details (table structure, example data, what you have tried, and what issue you see specifically with data)

Comment: Because you have no other requirement, see the answer from @Barmar.  That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the `id` column when inserting from `B` to `A`.

```
INSERT INTO table_A (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table_B
```

The columns listed are all the columns except the `id` column. I assume this is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, so new IDs will be assigned for them after merging.

Before you ask: No, there's no shortcut to select all columns except `id`. You have to list them all explicitly.

Comment: What query? Don't try to put long code in comments. Edit the question.

Comment: Added now, was to quick to press enter.

Comment: If the table has foreign key constraints, you need to add the related rows to the parent table before you do this merger.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I ran the following query: INSERT INTO table_A (my_columns_here) SELECT my_columns_here FROM DB2.table_B; But I received "ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (DB1.table_A, CONSTRAINT Table_A_data_id_4bfc720a_fk_data_id FOREIGN KEY (data_id) REFERENCES Table_C_data (id))"